# WordPress: get_permalink() doesn't take me from the excerpt to the full post

Tags: php, wordpress

**If one day someone else is looking at this in the future with the same problem, here is an update:**

UPDATE: Okay, you need to create a single.php and put the loop in that with the_content();

I have a problem here and hopefully it is something small that I over looked.

**What I want:**

I want only an excerpt of a post to be displayed with a link underneath in WordPress. When I click on the link I want it to show me the full post.

**What I tried:**

I looked at the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt) to find out how to do this and read to put this code into my file:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> Read More...</a>
```

or

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return ' <a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . 
'">' . __('Read More', 'your-text-domain') . '</a>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```

**What happens:**

A link will appear under the excerpt however when I click on it I am taken to a page with just an excerpt rather than the full post.

**My request:**

What change would I have to make to have the permalink take me to the full post? Below is a list of my code from content.php

```
<?php

if (have_posts()) :
   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?>

    <p style="color:white"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
    <div class="postContent" style="align:center;">

    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> Read More...</a>

    </div>

    <?php

endwhile;

else :
?>
<p>Sorry no posts matched your criteria.</p>
<?php
endif;?>
```

Comment: can you provide the site url?

Answer (score 1):

get_permalink() always send you to full post detail page. 
-> in your case may be you have edited page.php, single.php or function.php to display content limit. 
-> or check your theme options area for the content limit option if you are using any purchased theme.

Comment: Hi there, it's a simple theme I made and I am still stumped. I thank you for your help and trying.

Comment: can you please show us your single.php & page.php code files.

Answer (score 1):

I have facing the same issue and I used the below code and it works prefectly fine for me.

```
function custom_excerpt_more( $more ) {
return sprintf( '<br /><a class="read-more" href="%1$s">%2$s</a>',
    get_permalink( get_the_ID() ),
    __( 'Read More >>', 'textdomain' )
);
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'custom_excerpt_more' );
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, sadly that still didn't work but I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this edited code**

```
<?php

if (have_posts()) :
   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?>

    <p style="color:white"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
    <div class="postContent" style="align:center;">

    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"> Read More...</a>

    </div>

    <?php

endwhile;

else :
?>
<p>Sorry no posts matched your criteria.</p>
<?php
endif;?>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying Jasbir, sadly it didn't help but I appreciate it!